# React Select does not show the value when selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

i'm new to react-redux and i'm having two issues. I'm using eract select plus like this:

```
<Select
          id="portf"
          options={opts}
          onChange={value => portfolioSelector(value)}
          placeholder="Select Portfolio"
        />
```

But when i select another value this value even though is triggered it is not shown it the field. Another issue is that i want to set initial value to my selector so in my container i write:

```
const initialValues = fromJS({
  market: { label: 'All', value: 'All' },
  prodType: { label: 'All', value: 'All' }
});
```

When i execute my project i can see that in the state these values do exist but the don't shown  in my select field. For the second case i use react-select in redux form and i have implement it with the following way:

```
<Select
    {...props}
    value={props.input.value}
    onChange={value => props.input.onChange(value)}
    onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
    options={props.options}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
  />
```

Comment: How is your `onChange` action dispatched? How does your reducer look like?

Comment: case SET_PORTFOLIO_ID:
      return userSettings
        .set('currentPortfolioId', action.payload.currentPortfolioId); This is the case for my reducer. In the first select in the onchange i dispatch the action portfolioSelector

Comment: You'll have to show us the complete code stack. Reducer, action, dispatching that action, injecting data from the store in this "form" component, the component itself. The code you provided looks correct.

Comment: With alll respect i dont think it has something to do with reducer. I may forget to declare some function in my select component

Comment: Well then you debug it yourself. How can we help if the code you're showing us is irrelevant? I asked for more code because obviously the problem is not here.

Answer (score 1):

I just dealt with this problem, and I found it helpful to somewhat abstract the `Select` into its own component.  To do this, you can make a component (`ReactReduxSelect.jsx`) that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import style from 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

// define portfolioSelector somehow
// or you could pass it as a property:
//     portfolioSelector: React.PropTypes.func

class ReactReduxSelect extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Select
                name={this.props.name}
                value={this.state.selected}
                options={this.props.options}
                onChange={(value) => { 
                    this.setState({ selected: value });
                    portfolioSelector(value);
                }}
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            />
        );
    }
}

ReactReduxSelect.propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: React.PropTypes.string,
    options: React.PropTypes.array
};

export default ReactReduxSelect;
```

The cool thing about implementing it this way is that it then can be updated within the native Redux state tree.  So if you go back to your page where you want to embed this control (`MyTotallySickReactReduxWebpage.jsx` or whatever), you can import the component ...

```
import ReactReduxSelect from './ReactReduxSelect';
```

And then embed it in your code ...

```
const ArtifactGenerator = ({
    // my totally awesome props
}) => (
    // some react redux stuff w/ divs and { and js and all that jazz
    <ReactReduxSelect
        name="portf"
        options={[
             { label: 'Market', value: 'All' },
             { prodType: { label: 'ProdType', value: 'All' }
        ]}
        placeholder="Select Portfolio"
     />
     // whatever other groovy code you want in there
);

// the rest of your props and export code or whatever for the page
```

I'm not totally sure what you were trying to do with your `initialValues` there, that syntax doesn't look right to me, so I just kind of wrote something I think is more likely to work, but you can fairly easily adjust this to fit your needs.  Hope this helps!